# Find and count matches between two arrays in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to make a table that tracks pupil progress. Upon entry, pupils are given a predicted grade in all their subjects. Later in the year, their teachers give them an exam (which has a grade) and then give a set of new predicted grades.

This gives me two tables (each on a different sheet)...

```
-------------------------------------
-Entry   -          Subject         -
-------------------------------------
-Student - Art  -  Maths  -  French -
-------------------------------------
- Jane   -   U  -   U     -  n      -
-------------------------------------
- Alice  -   E  -   A+     - n      -
-------------------------------------
- Tom    -   D  -   A     -  c      -
-------------------------------------
```

and

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-Later   -                         Subject                           -
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-Student - Art Exam -  Art New Grade - Maths Exam - Maths New Grade  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------
- Jane   -   U      -   U            -  E         -    E             -
----------------------------------------------------------------------
- Alice  -   D      -   D            -  A+         -   A+            -
----------------------------------------------------------------------
- Tom    -   C      -   B            -  A         -    A+            -
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have created a dashboard that has two drop downs where users can select the subject and then the comparison (exam grade, new grade, best possible grade, ...). Using SUMPRODUCT I can take that input and easily count the grades in the matching columns.

What I want to do is create a table similar to the one below that can show how the pupils have changed between the two tracking periods...

```
--------------------------------------------
- Subject -          New Grade             -
-   Art   - n - U - E - D - C - B - A - A+ -
--------------------------------------------
- E    n  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -    -
-- -----------------------------------------
- n    U  -   - 1 -   -   -   -   -   -    -
-- -----------------------------------------
- t    E  -   -   -   - 1 -   -   -   -    -
-- -----------------------------------------
- r    D  -   -   -   -   -   - 1 -   -    -
-- -----------------------------------------
- y    C  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -    -
--------------------------------------------
-      B  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -    -
--------------------------------------------
-      A  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -    -
--------------------------------------------
-     A+  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -    -
--------------------------------------------
```

Each cell counts the number of times it finds matching values between the two arrays where subject = chosen value (in this case Art) and comparison = chosen value (in this case new grade). I don't mind null values being zero or blank. I need to have the count of matches so I can then look at how many pupils are making progress (getting a letter earlier in the alphabet than the test upon entry suggested).

Ideally, I'll also end up making both rows and columns selectable so teachers can compare exam result to new predicted grade.

In my two arrays, the students appear in the same order (one less criteria to worry about) but the subjects and comparators don't. (NB - I've been using concatenation to merger subject and comparator)

All the help I've seen so far expects the data to be in just two rows, but I've 20 subjects and then each subject can have 5 or so comparisons to be made!

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B3=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$5,0,MATCH($A$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$2,0)))*(C$2=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$3:$E$5,0,MATCH($A$2 & " New Grade",Sheet2!$B$2:$E$2,0))))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($B3=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$5,0,MATCH($A$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$2,0)))*(C$2=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$3:$E$5,0,MATCH($A$2 & " New Grade",Sheet2!$B$2:$E$2,0)))))
```

[image]

If you don't mind the `0`s then the just the true part of the above if statement will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B3=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$5,0,MATCH($A$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$2,0)))*(C$2=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$3:$E$5,0,MATCH($A$2 & " New Grade",Sheet2!$B$2:$E$2,0))))
```

---

**For Reference:**

Entry sheet (Sheet1):

[image]

New Grade Sheet (Sheet2)

[image: ![enter image description here]

One caveat, the Students must be in the same order.

Comment: Dear Scott 

THANKYOU! 

That worked an absolute treat, and thank you for such helpful illustrations as well!